# How do I drag from Explorer into Visual Studio without turning off UAC?

Tags: windows, uac

Surely there is a setting somewhere that can stop the stupid UAC issues blocking my drag and drop operation. Visual Studio has to run in admin mode for half the things I do and Explorer shouldn't have to run in some fancy admin mode just to get around this issue.

I just want to tell UAC to do its thing normally but bugger off when interfering with my drag and drop operations. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the option:

Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Local Security Policy > Local Policies > Security Options > User Account Control: Only elevate UIaccess applications that are installed in secure locations

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem stems from the fact that VS runs with administrative rights, and your drag & drop operations run as a normal user (you).  Probably the easiest way around this issue is to disable UAC, but maybe there's a more elegant solution out there...

Comment: Yeah it's because the file being dragged is coming from a lower security zone. It shits me though because these fine grained security concerns are getting in my way and irritating me...

Comment: Almost every dev I know just turns off UAC (especially on Vista -- Windows 7's isn't quite as bad).  It sucks, I know, but you're a dev, right?  Is UAC really saving you from blowing up your computer, or is it just getting in the way?  If it's in your way, turn it off.  I'm sure some security guru is cringing right now, but honestly we have to be able to *use* the computer, right? :)

Comment: Yeah... I have succumbed to turning off UAC. The popups and stuff don't even bother me, but blocking a drag and drop operation because of security concerns is crossing the line from bearable to pissing me off. It's interesting because I can copy and paste from one security zone to another but i can't drag to open. Grrr. Bye bye UAC!